# CSS Transform not working in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-transforms

I am attempting to rotate or transform a div using the CSS Transform property. Here is my transform CSS Code:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
-o-transform: rotate(270deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0);
transform: rotate(270deg);
```

The above code works great in all but IE 8. I need to find a way to support IE 8.

How can I create a fallback for IE8?

Note: I am using jQuery (1.8.2), HTML 5 Doctype and modernizr if that makes a difference in the answer you provide. I prefer a CSS only solution but willing to use a javascript/jQuery solution.

[Here is a fiddle with the HTML and CSS.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/Gh5YG/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see your "filter:" rotation to 3, it will give a 270 degree rotation in IE 8 (and downward to v5.5, IIRC).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532918(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, If I use that it messes up IE9, go figure. I will use IE Conditional Stylesheets for IE8 and below and IE9 and above.

Comment: I thought that might happen, but I wasn't sure. Conditional comments will definitely work around it.