# Using HTML hotspot to manage rotated sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the below menu that needs to be rotated with a slight angle:

[image]
<sub>(source: [maroonlemoon.com](http://maroonlemoon.com/rotated.png))</sub>

I have managed to achieve the look using nested divs for each menu strip (container div has the yellow background image, and the embedded div has a background image linked to an image with the text of each menu section)

```
<div id="the-menu" style="position:absolute; z-index:9998; left:120px; top:-5px; width:255px; height:300px;">
    <div id="home-strip" align="right" style="position:absolute; z-index:1; left:0px; width:216px; height:112px; background-image:url('images/menu-sliced.png'); background-position: 0px 0px;">
        <div onclick="javascript:alert('home');" style="cursor:pointer; position:relative; width:90px; height:35px; top:9px; left:6px;  background-image:url('images/menu-text.png');"></div>
    </div> 
    <div id="about-strip" align="right"  style="position:absolute; z-index:2; left:10px; top:30px; width:216px; height:112px; background-image:url('images/menu-sliced.png'); background-position: 0px 0px;">
        <div onclick="javascript:alert('about');" style="cursor:pointer; position:relative; width:90px; height:35px; top:10px; left:4px;  background-image:url('images/menu-text.png'); background-position: 0px -38px; background-repeat:no-repeat"></div>
    </div> 
    <div id="classes-strip" align="right"  style="position:absolute; z-index:3; left:20px; top:60px; width:216px; height:112px; background-image:url('images/menu-sliced.png'); background-position: 0px 0px;">
        <div style="cursor:pointer; position:relative; width:90px; height:35px; top:6px; left:4px;  background-image:url('images/menu-text.png'); background-position: 0px -76px; background-repeat:no-repeat"></div>
    </div> 
    <div id="team-strip" align="right"  style="position:absolute; z-index:4; left:30px; top:90px; width:216px; height:112px; background-image:url('images/menu-sliced.png'); background-position: 0px 0px;">
        <div style="cursor:pointer; position:relative; width:90px; height:37px; top:7px; left:4px;  background-image:url('images/menu-text.png'); background-position: 0px -116px; background-repeat:no-repeat"></div>
    </div> 
    <div id="facilities-strip" align="right" style="position:absolute; z-index:5; left:40px; top:120px; width:216px; height:112px; background-image:url('images/menu-sliced.png'); background-position: 0px 0px;">
        <div style="cursor:pointer; position:relative; width:90px; display:block; height:40px; top:10px; left:-3px;  background-image:url('images/menu-text.png'); background-position: 6px -157px; background-repeat:no-repeat"></div>
    </div> 
    <div id="schedule-strip"  align="right" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; left:50px; top:150px; width:216px; height:112px; background-image:url('images/menu-sliced.png'); background-position: 0px 0px;">
        <div style="cursor:pointer; position:relative; width:90px; display:block; height:35px; top:10px; left:4px;  background-image:url('images/menu-text.png'); background-position: 0px -196px; background-repeat:no-repeat"></div>
    </div> 
    <div id="contact-strip"  align="right" style="position:absolute; z-index:7; left:60px; top:180px; width:216px; height:112px; background-image:url('images/menu-sliced.png'); background-position: 0px 0px;">
        <div style="cursor:pointer; position:relative; width:90px; display:block; height:40px; top:10px; left:-5px;  background-image:url('images/menu-text.png'); background-position: 8px -234px; background-repeat:no-repeat"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Don't mind the inline styling. My problem is that I want to create a hover and click state for each menu section (with an angle) but achieving this with native HTML seems a bit challenging as divs will be intersecting. Please refer to the below snapshot for clarification:

[image]
<sub>(source: [maroonlemoon.com](http://maroonlemoon.com/rotated2.png))</sub>

Your help will be so much appreciated and I want a solution that works on all major browsers (I have researched a jQuery plugin that does the trick but isn't cross-browser compatible) Should I use classic html hotspots to do this. I kind of hate using them and feel they're no longer used for this purpose

Comment: Have you considered just using an image map? They've been around just about as long as the internet, and they are comparitively trivial to use; you just need one image and you can draw arbitrarily complex polygons at any angle you want. They are universally supported - first support was in Mosaic 1.1! For super-fancy stuff, you can use Imagemapster: http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/ (I've designed full HTML5 apps with both techs, and it just works)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this with CSS:

You would have to apply the transform: rotate(150deg); style to your  or your  tags that you want rotated.

```
div{
    transform: rotate(150deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(150deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Here's an example of rotating something using CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/hTx2w/1/

Comment: My only problem with this approach is that it's only supported in IE9+

Comment: You can rotate down to 5.5 using other properties: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12701854/2574944. Use browser conditional stylesheets so it wont mess up IE9+

Comment: Using the filter option for IE 8 and lower can only give me either 0,90,270 degree rotations which won't work here for my design, but thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes old tech is the best tech.

```
<html><head></head><body>
<img src="http://maroonlemoon.com/rotated2.png" name="example" usemap="#nav_map" id="example" />
<map name="nav_map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="201,4,89,47,100,75,216,29" href="#">
</map>
</body></html>
```

[image: Screenshot from Dreamweaver]

Dreamweaver even builds the tools for making them right into the basic interface, if you happen to use said software - but there are lots of online tools that help you draw the boxes and it'll generate the code for you to use too.

6 more simple lines of  tags, link them to where you want them to go, make sure you provide proper alt text for screen readers and the disabled, and off you go.